# How to verify if all the columns are incorporated in the merged DataFrame by using simple comparison Operator in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here I am creating 2 dataframes and then merging them. Now, How to verify if all the
columns are incorporated in the merged DataFrame by using simple comparison Operator in Python?

```
import pandas as pd

# elements of first dataset
first_Set = {'Prod': ['Laptop', 'Mobile Phone',
                        'Desktop', 'LED'],
            'Price_1': [25000, 8000, 20000, 35000]
            }

# creation of Dataframe 1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(first_Set, columns=['Prod', 'Price_1'])
print(df1)

# elements of second dataset
second_Set = {'Prod': ['Laptop', 'Mobile Phone',
                        'Desktop', 'LED'],
            'Price_2': [25000, 10000, 15000, 30000]
            }

# creation of Dataframe 2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(second_Set, columns=['Prod', 'Price_2'])
print(df2)

#merging datasets on Cloumn = Prod
df_tech = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Prod')
print(df_tech)
```

Comment: **#1** do an outer merge instead, and those don't find a match will have some `np.nan` in their rows. **#2** before merge, use `isin` to compare the 'Prod' columns from both dfs and see who from one df are missing in another df. **#3** use `isin` to compare your merged df with each of the original dfs to find out who are missing in the merged df.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, that works. I did it in 2 steps because i need to check if df1 & df2 is in df_tech. Like this,
print(df1.isin(df_tech)) ;
print(df2.isin(df_tech))

also, i tried :
x = df1.isin(df_tech) ;
y = df2.isin(df_tech) ;
print(x) and (y)

Does this seems right? Is there any better way to do the verification in 1 statement?

Comment: Please check my answer out

Answer (score 0):

Let's say my modified `df1` and `df2` have different sets of `'Prod'`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Prod': ['Mobile Phone', 'Desktop', 'LED'], 'Price_1': [8000, 20000, 35000]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Prod': ['Laptop', 'Mobile Phone', 'Desktop'], 'Price_2': [25000, 10000, 15000]})
```

By default, `pd.merge` gives you an inner merge so you only see the matched.

```
df_tech = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'Prod')
print(df_tech)

           Prod  Price_1  Price_2
0  Mobile Phone     8000    10000
1       Desktop    20000    15000
```

Approach 1 is to do instead an outer merge,

```
option1 = df1.merge(df2, on='Prod', how='outer')
```

And check which rows have `np.nan` for identifying those that could have missed out from an inner merge:

```
print(option1[option1.isna().any(axis=1)])

     Prod  Price_1  Price_2
2     LED  35000.0      NaN
3  Laptop      NaN  25000.0
```

And, `LED` and `Laptop` as expected.

Or, another approach, is to check dataframe-by-dataframe the original two with the merged one, using `isin`,

```
option2a = df1[~df1['Prod'].isin(df_tech['Prod'])]
option2b = df2[~df2['Prod'].isin(df_tech['Prod'])]
```

`option2a`, for example, will give us rows that don't get carried on to the merged dataframe

```
print(option2a)
  Prod  Price_1
2  LED    35000
```

and similar for `option2b`

```
print(option2b)
     Prod  Price_2
0  Laptop    25000
```